# GNOME Wacom Tablet settings pannel don't show Waltop Evo tablet

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, tablet

In general, [Waltop Evo Graphic Tablet](http://www.waltop.com/english/01_products/02_detail.php?SID=145) works but I can't configure it with Wacom Tablet settings pannel (Settings>Wacom Tablet). It shows "Please plug in or turn on your Wacom tablet ..."

More info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux me 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-2 (2014-11-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 172f:0510 Waltop International Corp. 
<...>
```

I also set custom configuration in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-my-wacom.conf` to use `wacom` driver:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom Waltop USB device class"
        MatchUSBID "172f:*"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

(After that `xsetwacom` started recognising it):

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Waltop International Corp. Battery-free Graphics Tablet stylus  id: 11  type: STYLUS    
Waltop International Corp. Battery-free Graphics Tablet pad id: 12  type: PAD
```

I also created `/usr/share/libwacom/waltop-battery-free-tablet.tablet`:

```
[Device]
Name=Waltop International Corp.
DeviceMatch=usb:172f:0510
Class=Bamboo
Width=10
Height=6

[Features]
Stylus=true
Reversible=false
Touch=false
Ring=false
Ring2=false
NumStrips=0
Buttons=2
```

Could please somebody tell me what I did wrong? How to make `Wacom Tablet` settings pannel recognise my tablet?